# Передача данных из второго потока, через сигналы -- слоты с подтверждение приема в основном потоки

Tags: c++, qt

Есть массив структур, достаточно большого размера. Передаю этот массив структур из второго потока в основной с помощью сигналов и слотов. Так как объем данных достаточно большей то возникает вопрос как мне во втором потоки получить подтверждение что данные переданы?

Comment: А что с ними (данными) может случиться? Зачем нужно это подтверждение?

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса, добавьте пример кода, иллюстрирующий интересующий вас кейс